# how to encode a shell script so others can run it but they can not read it

Tags: command-line, scripts, programming, encoding, utf-8

I want to encode a script, so others can run that script to get relevant result but when they run command cat  it should throw output in encoded format.

Comment: Not a script, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/can-a-script-be-executable-but-not-readable for a nice discussion.

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/801133/354511